# How to change an Angular6 layout based on the url?

Tags: angular, layout, themes, url-routing

We're going to build a new Angular6 application which need to have a different layout for each url.

So:

- https://green.url.com => green layout
- https://red.url.com => red layout

etc.

The subdomains won't be a color, but the name of a company.

In our current application we rewrite the chosen template based on a session (storage) that is set the first time and being read in Angular.
It works, but it seems to be a bit of a workaround and is not fail proof.

What's the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Just checking, when you mean layout, you don't mean theme (colours), right?

Comment: I indeed meant to change the layout - regarding colors and images - based on the company's corporate identity

Answer (score 1):

You want check the sub domain and on the basis of that you need to change the background color. You must be using AuthGuard in your application, so you can easily extract the subDomain by using this:

```
fullURL = (window.location.host).split('.');
const subDomain = fullURL[0];
```

Then you can return the subDomain and get it in your whatever component and in the constructor you can simply math the subDomain, like this:

```
if (subDomain === 'green') {
    document.body.style.background = 'green or #5fba7d'
    // you can use body class
    document.body.className = "greenTheme";
}

if (subDomain === 'red') {
    document.body.style.background = 'red or #f00'
    // you can use body class
    document.body.className = "redTheme";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Angular's app-routing module, which is the best approach.

You can find an exemple in this part of Angular's webpage tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5